# Vue.js + jQuery UI draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, vue.js

To make components draggable I have written a new vue directive like this

```
Vue.directive('drag', {
  bind: function () {
    $(this.el).draggable();
  }
});
```

and I make them draggable on `bind`.
This works fine in the inspector and if I drag the cards I see how `top` and `left` change, but it does not physically! I mean the cards stay on their place.
[Screenshot of the inspector. Looks fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIkwU.png)

I have tried it with `helper: "clone"` and this works (I can see the clone being dragged). But this isn't what I want.

If I select every card by the class selector like:

```
$(".card").draggable();
```

it works fine too, but I don't want to make all other elements draggable again after I added just a new one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That type of positioning usually requires `display: absolute` or `display: relative`. Is your CSS interfering with that?

Comment: I have a hotfix for it and it works, but I'm not satisfied: 
`setTimeout(function () {
          $(this.el).draggable();
      }.bind(this), 20);`

Normally jQuery is setting this, but your comment points in the right direction.

Comment: Vue's `nextTick` might be what you need in this case. It invokes a function after any pending DOM updates have been performed.

Comment: put $(this.el).draggable() in update?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a jquery ui function, you need to call it with nextTick. Like this:

```
Vue.nextTick(function () {
        $('.card').draggable();
});
```

Comment: Like this I would add the draggable property to every card again after each tick. That's not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to use nextTick. Since the issue is that jQuery draggable is being called before the elements are loaded you can do what everyone else that uses jQuery does and use jQuery's .ready method

```
Vue.directive('draggable', {
    bind: function () {
        var self = this
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(self.el).draggable()
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the entire view has been rendered
    $('.card').draggable();
  })
}
```

By the way, $(this.el).draggable() does not work, I don't know why